# Fetch the input type date value via ajax

Tags: plugin-development

I am new to ajax and I've been struggling for 3 days now on how to solve my problem. I am trying to fetch the value of the date input (input type="date" in html)and pass (post method) it to ajax so that it can be processed. My goal is to be able to update a certain post meta value of multiple posts filtered via post date in a specific date range selected by user using an html 5 date input.

Currently I only have a button which updates all the post meta value but the date range must be manually entered into the code, I couldn't make it possible to be dynamic where a user can select a date range like update post meta values of posts between April 1, 2013 and May 1, 2013.

My working ajax which can run my function is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#update-form').submit(function(){
        data = {
            action: 'update_beginning_balance'
        };
        $.post(ajaxurl, data, function(updatebbal) {
            $('#updated-bbal-result').html(updatebbal);
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I tried to use $(#id).val which I referred from here http://api.jquery.com/val/. I hope you could give me some ideas on how to $_POST my input date fields via ajax.

Or do you have any idea on how can I accomplish this task without using ajax? I am better with PHP compared to AJAX/JavScript.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to post the value as soon as user has entered the date and click somewhere else, this might help you:

```
 jQuery('#your-name').on('blur', function(){
   var date_Value = this.value;
   var ajaxdata = {
        action: 'process_date',
        date_value: date_Value
    };
   jQuery.post(ajaxurl, ajaxdata, function(res){ 
      /* whatever you want to do, res contains the output generated by your php file*/  
    });
 })
```

As you are using admin ajax, make a function to process this data.

```
function process_Date(){
  $date = $_POST['date_value'];
  /* do whatever you want to do with your $date*/
 /* return an output */
  die(1);
}
add_action('wp_ajax_process_date', 'process_Date');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_process_date', 'process_Date');
```

Add this function to your file where you are having other functions.

Comment: Hello dot1, thanks for that, I will try it out first and will provide a feedback on what will be the result. Thanks again regards!

Comment: That's fine, if that doesn't works provide me a link or better details.

Comment: Hello, I have a very long reply, so I paste it here http://pastebin.com/QeKDwhw3 thanks

Comment: Okay I will try that new code. Will response again if it will work.

Comment: I used this http://pastebin.com/uvPLCuPd but I can't see any feedback. ajaxurl points to the wordpress' WP-Admin/admin-ajax.php. Thanks

Comment: Hello, the javascript now works, thank you, but in the WP function you gave I added die(); because it gave a zero 0 value if it is not present. I am trying to echo the $date = $_POST['date_value']; but it doesn't echo the value of the date rather it shows blank and it shows zero if I removed the die();. Thanks again for your help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Ya I forgot to mention to add die(1); in end to get proper results, so it's working??

If yes then mark it as answer.

Comment: The javascript/ajax works, but may I know how can I determine if the selected date was really posted? I tried to echo the $date but it shows blank page. Thanks

Comment: you can check the data posted in Browser debugger , and the response you get from ajax request.
or use debugger console to print the output, as I already told you, in the ajax request put a line console.log(this.value); and then check what you get in console. remove the line after.

Comment: Thanks, yes, I can see now the posted data. Thank you very much, just need some tweaks on my end to meet my requirements, but that is another issue, this one (posting data) is already solved. Thanks

Comment: That's Nice. :)